# cannot shh into lxc container even after changing config file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-18.04, lxc

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have created an lxc-container called ctn and can log into it by using `lxc-attach`, ending up as the root user. When running the following with the ip shown by running `lxc-ls`:

`sudo shh -n root@10.*.*.*`

After entering the password, I get the following message:

`Permission denied, please try again.`

This prompts me to change `PermitRootLogin` to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I did this for both client and container and reset the ssh process. I still get the same message, how could this be?

Comment: Are you sure that the password is correct? Check the log (/var/log/auth.log in Ubuntu, I think) for info, or the journal. Change the password to something simple and try again. Configure key-based authentication and try again. Launch the sshd with verbosity. What's the -n option for, by the way? I thought it is only used to run remote processes in the background.

Comment: `PermitRootLogin` is a server setting. What do you mean by "reset the ssh process"? You need to restart the sshd service in the container.

Comment: Sorry, the -n was a misspelling. I am sure the password is correct. In /var/log/auth.log I have the following: ```pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.*.*.*  user=root
Jan 23 01:42:31 ctn sshd[116]: Failed password for root from 10.*.*.* port 52684 ssh2```

Comment: And i restarted sshd with ```systemctl restart sshd```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the root password and try to use something simple for testing purpose and then try again & share the logs with us.

Comment: I did, as simple as possible. Get the following log in the container, since the password change.

Comment: ```Jan 23 16:12:40 ctn sshd[87]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jan 23 16:13:09 ctn passwd[187]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for root
Jan 23 16:14:41 ctn sshd[190]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.*.*.*  user=root
Jan 23 16:14:44 ctn sshd[190]: Failed password for root from 10.*.*.* port 39132 ssh2
```

Comment: ```Jan 23 16:16:19 ctn sshd[190]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 10.*.*.* port 39132 [preauth]
Jan 23 16:16:33 ctn sshd[192]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.*.*.*  user=root
Jan 23 16:16:35 ctn sshd[192]: Failed password for root from 10.*.*.* port 39144 ssh2
Jan 23 16:17:01 ctn CRON[194]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)```